# Ant copy with many mappers problem

Tags: ant

I am want to copy all directory to another directory but also I must rename one file.
I am trying this:

```
<copy todir="destDir" enablemultiplemappings="true">
  <fileset dir="sourceDir"/>
  <compositemapper>
    <identitymapper />
    <globmapper from="oldFileName" to="newFileName"/>
  </compositemapper>
</copy>
```

But this task copy all files, and than copy renamed file. And in destDir directory I have two files: **destDir\oldFileName** and **destDir\newFileName**. But I need only **destDir\newFileName**. Can someone help me with this?

**EDITED:**
 I need to copy all files form sourceDir to destDir, and rename only file with name "oldFileName".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `enablemultiplemappings="false"`, and swap the order of your mappers:

```
<copy todir="destDir">
  <fileset dir="sourceDir" />
  <compositemapper>
    <globmapper from="oldFileName" to="newFileName" />
    <identitymapper />
  </compositemapper>
</copy>
```

Without multiple mappings enabled the first mapping that produces a filename 'wins'.  So for the files needing a rename, the glob will apply.  For all other files the identity mapper will name them as-is.